# Creating a mongo view that depends on the current time

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, view, aggregation

I have a collection that has a date field and I want to create a mongo view that filter all the documents by the current date. For example, I want my view to contain all the documents of the last 7 days.

I have a javascript script that creates the view with aggregation pipeline. I used javascript method- new Date() to write the condition of the last 7 days:

```
{
  "$lt": [
     {"$subtract": [new Date(), "$DateOfDocument"]}, // difference in milliseconds
      1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7              // 7 days in milliseconds
  ]
}
```

But when I execute the script that creates the view, mongo calculates 'new Date()' and than creates the view, with the result of 'new Date()' as ISODate. **Now the aggregation pipeline calculates the view by the last time I executed the script, not by the actual current date.**

```
{
  "$lt": [
      {"$subtract": [ISODate("2018-02-05T06:52:32.10+0000"), "$DateOfDocument"]},
      604800000
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to get a view filtered by the current date? Any aggregation method for the current date, like oracle's **'sysdate'**? I don't want to execute the script that recreate the view every time I want to read the view.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this feature is in the works for MongoDB 3.7. 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23656

Comment: Now listed as a required fix for 4.1; hopefully it gets added this time!